# passing value from iframe overlay to parent page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a question about jquery and colorbox overlay. I can't find good solution on stackoverflow.

I would like to get some value (myvalue) from iframe overlay.

Code in my parent child (home.php) :

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({
iframe:true,
width:"1000px",
height:"500px",     
    // Begin to clos the overlay
onCleanup: function() {
var myvalue = $("#myvalue").val();
alert('myvalue');
}
}
```

Link to open my iframe :

```
<a href="child.php" class="iframe">OPEN OVERLAY BY IFRAME METHOD</a>
```

Code in my iframe overlay (child.php) :

```
$(".mydiv").click(function(){
    window.parent.$(this).attr('value'); 
    parent.$.colorbox.close();
    return false;
});
```

Html in my overlay (child.php) :

```
<div class="mydiv" value="TESTPASSINGVALUE"></div>
```

An idea to helping me ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem with localStorage

Code in child page :

```
$(".mydiv").click(function(){
val = $(this).attr('value'); 
localStorage.setItem("myvalue", "val");
parent.$.colorbox.close();
return false;
});
```

Code in parent page :

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({
iframe:true,
width:"1000px",
height:"500px",     
// Begin to clos the overlay
onCleanup: function() {
var test = localStorage.myvalue;
alert(test);
}
}
```

Thank all for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to your iframe element. Suppose your iframe element has id "iframe". Then,

```
onCleanup: function() {
    var myvalue = $("#iframe").contents().find("#myvalue").val();
    alert('myvalue');
}
```

You need to use contents() to access content in an iframe. Also the iframe URL must be in the same domain as the parent (same origin policy)

Comment: Upvoting because your hint "use contents() to access content in an iframe" was the missing link for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myid", parent.document.body);
```

Comment: Thank you. I put your line on my iframe child page. If I write this on my parent page : `myvalue = $("#myvalue").val(); alert(myvalue);` I have an alert with "undefined"

Comment: Try to host your example on IIS and then test it